# Unable to send mail via SparkPost saved templates using python client

Tags: python, email, sparkpost

I'm trying to send mail using SparkPost SMTP API

```
response = spark.transmissions.send(
    recipients=['somemail@example.com'],
    text='hi',
    content={
        "template_id": "my-first-email",
        "from":{"name": "someone", "email": "no-reply@jhuthmatbolo.com"},
    },
    subject='Subject Line',
    substitution_data={
       "name": "Your Name"
    }
)
```

As per [documentation](https://developers.sparkpost.com/api/transmissions.html#header-using-a-stored-template) it should work but I am getting the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sendmail.py", line 69, in <module>
    sparkpost()
  File "sendmail.py", line 65, in sparkpost
    "name": "Rupesh"
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sparkpost/transmissions.py", line 254, in send
    results = self.request('POST', self.uri, data=json.dumps(payload))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sparkpost/base.py", line 41, in request
    **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sparkpost/base.py", line 16, in request
    raise SparkPostAPIException(response)
sparkpost.exceptions.SparkPostAPIException: Call to https://api.sparkpost.com/api/v1/transmissions returned 422, errors:

        required field is missing Code: 1400 Description: content.from is a required field
```

PS- Everything works fine with Postman examples provided by [Sparkpost](https://www.getpostman.com/run-collection/81ee1dd2790d7952b76a).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use a stored template (by setting `template_id`), you do not need to set `content` or `subject` since they are embedded in the template. You can make your call like this:

```
response = sp.transmissions.send(
    recipients=['you@me.com'],
    template='my-template-id'
)
```

Also, the `python-sparkpost` API client provides a layer on top of the SparkPost API so the parameters for `SparkPost.transmissions.send()` are not a 1:1 match for the API. The full documentation for `python-sparkpost` is [available here](https://python-sparkpost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

[Here's a relevant sample](https://github.com/SparkPost/python-sparkpost/blob/master/examples/transmissions/transmission_stored_template.py) from the Python client too.